# Connecting to Api in Angular production

Tags: angular, nginx, reverse-proxy, production

I'm creating a personal website using Angular, and hosting the website [www.mywebsite.com](http://www.mywebsite.com) using Hostinger. I'm trying to pull data from an api  https://api.alternative.me/fng/?limit=1 for a chart. When I developed locally, I was able to get around the CORS errors by creating a proxy.conf.json file. This way isn't working in production, as I get GET https://mywebsite.com/api/fng/?limit=1 404. I read we can use a reverse proxy with Apache/Nginx in production.

I installed nginx for windows, and then modified the nginx.conf file

```
 server {
    listen       80;
    server_name https://mywebsite.com;

    location /api/ {
      proxy_pass https://api.alternative.me/;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE';
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization';
    }

    location / {
      root C:\Users\Desktop\ProjectA\projectA\dist\project-a\src;
      index index.html;
    }
  }
```

This isn't working as in the console I get GET https://mywebsite.com/api/fng/?limit=1 404.
If this is the correct approach, how can I configure the file? If not how can I make an api call to https://api.alternative.me/fng/?limit=1 from my domain https://mywebsite.com in production without getting CORS errors? Thanks.

Comment: The proxy is only for the dev server. It should only be used to reflect your production setup during development. You need to fix this **on the server**.